# Jordan normal form if all the equations come out the same

Tags: linear-algebra

Can somebody help me with the **Jordan** form and the change of basis **T**?

\begin{bmatrix}
  6 & 6 & -15 \\
  1 & 5 & -5 \\ 
  1 & 2 & -2
 \end{bmatrix}

All three eigenvalues are λ=3 so we get:
\begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 6 & -15 \\
  1 & 2 & -5 \\
  1 & 2 & -5
 \end{bmatrix}

But all three equations are the same, the kernel **(M−λI)v=0** \begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  2/5
 \end{bmatrix}

After this step I can't progress any further.

Comment: The number of blocks associated to $\lambda$ in the Jordan Canonical form of $M$ is the nullity of $M-\lambda I$. I don't know what you mean by "all three equations are the same", but if you mean that the nullity is $1$ (that the dimension of the eigenspace is $1$), then that means you get exactly one block, so the Jordan form is a single $3\times  3$ block associated to $\lambda=3$.

Comment: I mean 3x+6y-15z; x+2y-5z; x+2y-5z are all equivalent, so when calculating the basis I need to find a vector v2 for which (M−λI)v2=v but it seems impossible if I have three different values in v.

Comment: If the rank of $M-\lambda I$ is $1$, then the nullity is $2$, so you get two blocks. You need to find an vector that is in $N(M-\lambda I)^2$ but not in $M-\lambda I$.

Comment: You've miscalculated the nullspace of $M-3I$ in any case. It has dimension $2$, not $1$.

Comment: You are trying to find the Jordan form. So, you need to compute two generalized eigenvectors generated by the eigenvalue $\lambda=3$.

Answer (score 1):

The rank of $M-3I$ is one; that means that its nullity (the dimension of the eigenspace associated to $\lambda = 3$ is $2$. This tells you the Jordan form will have exactly two blocks, so the Jordan form of your matrix is necessarily
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3&1&0\\
0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right).$$
(The number of blocks is the dimension of the eigenspace).

To find a Jordan canonical basis, we need an element of $N((M-3I)^2)$ that is not in $N(M-3I)$. Given your calculation of $M-3I$, the nullspace has rank $2$. It is given by all vectors $(x,y,z)^T$ with
$$\begin{align*} 
x&= -2s+5t\\
y&=s\\
z&=t
\end{align*}$$
with $s$ and $t$ arbitrary. E.g., $(5,0,1)$ is mapped by $M$ to $(15,0,3)=3(5,0,1)$, and $(-2,1,0)$ is mapped by $M$ to $(-6,3,0)=3(-2,1,0)$.

Now, $(M-3I)^2$ is the zero matrix. So we just need a vector that is not in $N(M-3I)$. For example, $(1,0,0)$ (there are many, many, many possibilities here!). Then We take $(M-3I)(1,0,0)^T$, $(1,0,0)^T$, and then find an eigenvector that is not a multiple of $(M-3I)(1,0,0)$ to complete the basis.

Since $(M-3I)(1,0,0)^T = (3,1,1)^T$ (note that it lies in $N(M-3I)$, with $s=t=1)$. Then we can take any vector in $N(M-3I)$ that is linearly independent from $(3,1,1)$, for example $(5,0,1)$ (many, many, many possibilities here as well!). So one possible Jordan canonical basis is $[ (3,1,1)^T, (1,0,0)^T, (5,0,1)^T]$.

Comment: So what I wrote as a the kernel (0,1,2/5) is just one of the possible values, thank you so much for the  answer and explanation!

Comment: @Ramboti: It doesn't even *span* the kernel (which is never just one nonzero vector). I am afraid you are very confused.

Comment: Yes, I am a little confused, why did you choose (5,0,1) and (-2,1,0) and is it a coincidence that they add up to (3,1,1)?

Comment: Also [(-15,-5,-5), (0,0,1), (0,1,2/5)] seems correct, I'm not sure for what purpose do I need to span the kernel in this example.

Comment: @Ramboti You have two parameters, $s$ and $t$. Setting $s=1,t=0$ gives one basis vector for the nullspace, and $s=0,t=1$ gives a second, guaranteed to be independent of the first. You should have covered this well before you start looking at Jordan forms.

Comment: @Ramboti You need to know what the kernel is i. order to pick a vector that is *not* in the kernel but **is** a generalized eigenvector. You are not just a "little" confused. You are a lot confused.

Answer (score 1):

When all entries are integers and the eigenvalues are integers  one may do this:  the characteristic polynomial  is $(\lambda - 3)^3.$

Next we want the **minimal polynomial**, which must be one of these:   $(\lambda - 3)^3 , \; \;$  $(\lambda - 3)^2 , \; \;$  $(\lambda - 3) . \; \;$

Well, $M-3I \neq 0,$  so the minimal polynomial is not the third choice. Easy to check (and not error -prone with integers)   that $(M-3I)^2 = 0$  So that is the minimal polynomial, $(\lambda - 3)^2 $

FACT:   the minimal polynomial shows, for each eigenvalue, the largest Jordan block (in case there are more than one block  for a specific eigenvalue).

There is a 2 by 2 block.  All we need is  to take  any (column) vector $w$ we like    with $ (M-3I)^2 w = 0 $  but $ (M-3I) w \neq 0 $  To keep the numbers small, I suggest
$$
w=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This will be the far right column in $P,$  where I am constructing $P^{-1}MP = J$ in Jordan form.
The middle column will  be $ v =(M-3I) w \neq 0 $  which is automatically an eigenvector. Here

$$
v=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

same as Arturo. For the left column, we need a genuine eigenvector    that is not a multiple of $v.$  Well, $(-2,1,0)^T$  is an eigenvector,  then $u = v + (-2,1,0)^T$  is still an eigenvector.

$$
u=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

THe resulting change of basis matrix is
$$
P=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&3&1 \\
2&1&0 \\
1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
It turns out that $\det P = 1,$  so we get no fractions in

$$
P^{-1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&-1 \\
0&-1&2 \\
1&2&5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then you just multiply to get $J = P^{-1} M P$

Here is one I made up, it takes a while to get all the numbers to work out nicely. You should do this next, start to finish.

$$
N=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
8&-3&-6 \\
1&4&-2 \\
1&-1&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: For example I could use (-2,1,0) still as u, right?

Comment: @Ramboti yes. That may change $\det P$ and $P^{-1}$ as well. I put in a similar example you should solve,  I called the matrix $N,$  you should construct $P$   such that $P^{-1} NP  = J$  is in Jordan form.

Comment: @Ramboti  no, $P^{-1}$ is easy to find, but $P^{-1}MP$  does not come out right.  Your left column $(1,1,0)^T$  is not a genuine eigenvector.  You need one generalized eigenvector and then two genuine, furthermore the choice of the generalized vector forces one of the genuines...

Comment: I made a mistake, it should have been [(4,2,1),(3,1,1),(1,0,0)]

Comment: Or [(5,1,2),(3,1,1),(1,0,0)]

Comment: I guess you are doing the exercise I made. All you need to do   is take your  matrix $P,$   find $P^{-1},$   then just multiply $P^{-1}NP$  to see if that is in Jordan form... Assuming that you are indicating, by your notation, [(column 1), (column 2), (column 3)]  I think it likely those will work. Not that your second choice has determinant $-1$  so the inverse may need to be adjusted  with that in mind. Anyway, I think you have it, you will benefit from checking it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I got  J= (5,0,0)(0,5,0)(0,1,5) [columns] so it checks out, thank you for the help, I think I get it now!